# Why is this Derivative of a Matrix equation true?

Tags: matrices

Why is the derivative 
$\frac\partial{\partial x} [-\frac12 (z-Hx)^TR^{-1}(z-Hx)] = H^{T}R^{-1}(z-Hx) $ ?
Why is this equation true?

I can see why the -(1/2) cancels out (because $(z-Hx)$ is being squared) and because the minus sign from the $H$ cancels out the other minus sign. But I am wondering specifically why is there an $H^{T}$ and not $H$ in the answer?

It should be noted that $x$ is a column vector of sixe $n$ and $R$ is a $n x n$ matrix. $z$ is a column vector of size $m$. $H$ is a transformation matrix of size $m x n$ .

Answer (score 0):

You're differentiating a scalar with respect to a vector, giving a vector whose $i$th component is obtained by differentiation with respect to $x_i$. Summing over repeated indices, $$-\frac{1}{2}\partial_i(H_{jk}x_k-z_j)(R^{-1})_{jl}(H_{lm}x_m-z_l)=-H^T_{ij}(R^{-1})_{jl}(Hx-z)_l=(H^TR^{-1}z-(Hx))_{i}.$$

Comment: There are no scalars in the equation. Does your answer change?

Comment: @ArielBaron The thing you differentiated is a scalar, $y\cdot R^{-1}y$ with $y:=z-Hx$.

Comment: no I am differentiating with respect to x. which is a vector

Comment: @ArielBaron That's exactly what I said; you differentiated a scalar with respect to a vector, giving a vector, whose $i$th component is what I gave you.

Comment: your result and mine are not the same